# Por que nós não ganhamos unicórnios?

Tags: debate

Estive visitando os sites do StackExchange em inglês e bem, unicórnios em toda a parte.
Puxa, achei que a gente também ganharia unicórnios... E o joguinho para minar moedas de unicórnio... E poder dar uma acelerada na minha reputação...

Where is the love? :(

Comment: eu ganhei 75 `unicoins`, mas não reparei onde, pra ser bem sincero estou perdido com esse lance de unicórnios e unicoins, exemplo: "remover o botão de downvote em todas as suas publicações, por sei lá quantos unicoins", sério mesmo isso? :X

Comment: Alguém precisa explicar pros gringos que aqui no Brasil também tem 1º de Abril

Comment: putz.. 1º de abril, nem me toquei X(, na vdd eu não tinha dado mt atenção, rsrs..

Comment: espero que tenhamos [Winter Bash](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winterbash) aqui no SOPT, eu gosto de chapéus :)

Comment: @Math Ano passado nós tivemos, ainda no começo do beta privado, então devemos continuar tendo

Comment: Essa versão do fórum não é exatamente a mesma que o Stackoverflow. Imagino que eles não instalaram o Unicoin aqui porque não era só uma questão de plug-and-play.